# Strange Results from Batch For Loop n++

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

All, I am working on a batch script which reads input from a text file into a for loop to perform a wget command.

The text of the file is:

```
BIO
CHM
```

An example of the for loop command is:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%b in (Text\foo.txt) do (
wget.exe --load-cookies=cookies.txt -O Foo\%%b_foo "http://foo.org/search/search=%%b"
```

The url is accessed properly using each line from the text file as a search parameter, but when saving the output of the wget command, the filenames are `n++BIO_foo` `CHM_foo`. The loop seems to be working, but the "n++" is throwing me off. Any ideas why this could be occurring? It only occurs for the first line in the text file.

Comment: You sure of what is in your foo.txt file? Do an `echo %%b` before your `wget` command.

Comment: After doing an echo, I get a strange output before the `wget` command. It looks like a n with three strange half boxes before BIO. That suggests that the textfile itself has an odd character(s) prior to BIO, but those character(s) are not visible.

Comment: My best guess is foo.txt is a utf-8 file and not ansi. Resave the file in notepad as ansi encoding.

Comment: That is exactly what the issue was. Once I manually set the file to ansi, everything worked properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Squashman provided me the proper clues to solve this issue. The text file was encoded as utf-8 rather than ansi, thus an issue was be introduced when attempting to read the file. Once the file type was changed (save as), the issue was solved.